# Replace a line with RandomAccessFile

Tags: java, io, randomaccessfile

I have a text file with this content:

```
Ehsan,12345,11111,1000
maryam,147258,222,5000
reza,758694,abcd,4600
Ali,564789,kfcg,7500
mohammad,658932,bnfgd,5800
zahra,758964,798564,6750
rasool,568974,457832,1400
Ahmad,785403,wasd,6900
Amir,3205809,man123,7000
Morad,1,1,8900
```

I read all line of it with `RandomAccessFile`:

```
Account2[] members = new Account2[10];
try {
  RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("d:\\myTxtFile.txt", "r");
  raf.seek(0);
  long position = raf.getFilePointer();
  int counter = 0;
  while(raf.length()> position){
    members[counter] = new Account2(raf.readLine(), position);
    position =raf.getFilePointer();
    counter++;
  }
} catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then in `Account2` I have a method to save file after changes:

```
private long position;
public Account2(String l, long p){
  super(l); 
  position = p;
}
public void saveFile(){
  try {
    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("d:\\myTxtFile.txt", "rw");
    raf.seek(position);
    String newContents = "my new contents here";
    //raf.writeChars(newContents.toString());
    raf.writeUTF(newContents);
  } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

But it destroy my text file and add some strange character in head of line and bring next line to tail of line. Why is this?

Comment: **Never** have empty catch statements. Who knows what exceptions you are missing. Please add an `e.printStacktrace()` and check nothing is printed.

Comment: I add it, but problem is not here

Comment: What does super(l) do? Which class is the parent class? Where are you calling saveFile() ? And why are you writing back the same file, and not to a separate file?

Comment: Hi Did you manage to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: `raf.writeUTF(newContents);` is "destroying your file" and causing the "strange characters" to appear. Instead u wanna use `raf.writeBytes(newContents);`

Furthermore I don't know what this code should accomplish but consider that u can't use a [RandomAcessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) to **insert** a string at a specified position. Instead your `saveFile()` method overwrites the beginning of every line with `"my new contents here"`. If both the old and the new String have the same length this is not a problem but apart from that this messes up your file too. To prevent that rewrite your file with the new contents. E.g. [java replace specific string in textfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23466179/java-replace-specific-string-in-textfile)