# Making the data from the csv file double when put in the Textbox

Tags: java

txtRate.setText(emp.getRate());

I cant display the data from the csv file in the textbox because it keeps on saying

double cannot be converted to java.lang.String.
My method is public Double getRate() 
If i try to make is public String it would work but i cant use the value for calculation because it already has been set 
to String

Comment: Also consider changing ` Double getRate()` to ` double getRate()`

Answer (score 1):

The class you are working on contains method with signature `setText(String value)` but there's no method with signature `setText(Double value)`.

When you call a method compiler checks the parameter type and tries to recognize what method should be in use for this case.

As you are using `Double` type for the parameter, the compiler is unable to find a method with signature `setText(Double value)` and you get the error you have reported in your question.

To overcome this issue, convert your parameter from `Double` to `String` type before passing it to `setText` method.

```
txtRate.setText(String.valueOf(emp.getRate()));
```

or

```
txtRate.setText(emp.getRate().toString());
```

But the second approach may throw `NullPointerException` if `emp.getRate()` returns null, so the first approach is safer.

In case you want to format your numbers in a fancy way, consider this tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

Comment: I just want it to remain double not convert to String. Because i need it for calculations. I cant add up String and an integer. How can i make it remain as Double?

Comment: You convert your Double to String only to put it to the text box. Your getRate() method returns Double and you can use it for calculations as well.

Comment: If my explanation is not clear, feel free to ask more questions.

Comment: Do you have a hardware store sample program?

Comment: Nope sorry, I don't have such sample application. If something is still not clear, ask more questions.

Comment: So i have a csv file. And i need to update a certain cell with a new number. How can i do it?

Comment: If you are working with a text (csv) file, I recommend to consider [RandomAccessFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) java class. CSV file consists of lines of data, so you can read a line, find a cell offset in this line, update the value of the cell, and [replace the updated string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23466179/java-replace-specific-string-in-textfile) in your csv file

Comment: Also, if you are working with MS Excel files, consider [Apache POI framework](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html)

Comment: Yes. I searched and most is RAF is the most recomended

Comment: That's because you need to navigate and change an arbitrary part of a file. If your csv file is a large one and you have many cells to update I would recommend the following approach: create a new csv (text) file, read line by line your source csv file, update these lines and put them to the new file. When you have finished, delete source csv file, and rename your new csv file to have the same name as had your source file before.

Comment: Do you know why

Comment: I did not understand your question. Why what? Please elaborate your question.

Comment: I have another problem.

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException:

Comment: For input string: "Rate" (in sun.misc.FloatingDecimal)

Comment: Looks like your string, that you are trying to convert to number contains delimiters or other formatting, that is not expected by your formatter when you call `parse` method. Make sure you have correct formatting pattern set for your formatter according to your source string.

Answer (score 0):

Displaying data on the textbox require variable to be string, But calculation require variable to be double the answer is when displaying cast to string and when calculation don't