# How to change the case of all characters in a text file to lowercase in java?

Tags: java

So if the contents of a text file is FCCCC, the output of the same text file should be fcccc.

I have written the following code

```
  import java.lang.*;
  import java.io.*;
  import java.io.FileWriter;
  import java.io.IOException;
  class A
  {
   public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
   {
      try 
      {
            FileReader reader = new FileReader("doc1.txt");
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("doc1.txt", true);
            int character=' ';
            char m;
            while ((character = reader.read()) != -1) 
            {
                m=Character.toLowerCase((char)character);
                System.out.println(m);
                writer.write(m);
            }
            reader.close();
            writer.close();
      } 
      catch (IOException e) 
      {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
 }
```

In the code above if the contents of the text file are FCCCC then the output is FCCCCfcccc.

What is the mistake in the code?

Comment: is that sysout or in the file you are getting "FCCCCfcccc" ?

Comment: Because I think, you are appending into the file thats why ? Try cleaning the content of file first and then write into file.

Comment: ok first read all contents from file, process then rewrite again

Comment: When you create a new FileWriter object, the boolean in the constructor determines whether it appends to the file instead of overwriting it. You should either set it to "false" or just use the "(File)" constructor instead of the "(File, boolean)" constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Your `writer` is writing to the same text file that your `reader` is reading from.

Try writing to a different text file.

Comment: True but I want the characters in the same text file to be replaced.

Comment: If you want to use the same file, possibly look into the answers for  [String.replaceAll()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23466179/java-replace-specific-string-in-textfile)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
import java.io.*;

public class TextFile {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
            File file1 = new File("intext.txt");
            File file2 = new File("outtext.txt"); 
            char CharCounter = 0;       
            BufferedReader in = (new BufferedReader(newFileReader(file1)));
            PrintWriter out = (new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file2)));

            int ch;
            while ((ch = in.read()) != -1){

                if (Character.isUpperCase(ch)){
                    Character.toLowerCase(ch);

                }
                out.write(ch);


            }
            in.close();
            out.close();
        }       
    }
```

and the delete old text and rename the new one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `java.io.RandomAccessFile`. It allows you to read and write to file and get file pointer and set file pointer. The program:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        RandomAccessFile raf = null;
        try {
            raf = new RandomAccessFile("C:\\Untitled.txt", "rw");

            long length = raf.length();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) length];
            long pointer = 0;
            while (raf.read(buffer) != -1) {
                String upperCase = new String(buffer).toUpperCase();
                raf.seek(pointer);
                raf.writeBytes(upperCase);
                pointer = raf.getFilePointer();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (raf != null)
                raf.close();
        }
    }
```

`raf.length()` returns number of bytes in file

`raf.read(buffer)` reads `buffer.length` amount of bytes into `buffer` array

`raf.seek(pointer);` set file pointer to position before current read

`raf.getFilePointer();` get file pointer position before next read to be able to write starting from this position.

Answer (score 0):

I search for my problem to solve my issue and see your code.
This is my code and give u in Console like whats you want.

I hope you Enjoy.

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;



public class WordCounter {
    private static String Say;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File("Top250imdbMovies.txt");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
           String line = scanner.nextLine();
           Say =  line.toLowerCase();
           System.out.println(Say);
         }
       }
    }
```